# Is every revolution a byproduct of a highly organized group of conscientious and professional organizers?

Tags: reference-request, revolutions

[This video](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1wecnm) is part of an interview with defected KGB spy [Yuri Bezmenov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Bezmenov). From about 2:45 to 3:10 in the clip Bezmenov claims:

> The immediate impulse to defect was Bangladesh crisis which was described by American correspondents as Islamic grassroots revolution, which is absolute baloney. There was nothing to do with Islam and there was no grassroots revolution. **Actually, there are no grassroots revolutions. Period. Any revolution is a byproduct of a highly organized group of conscientious and professional organizers, but it has nothing to do with grassroots.**

Is this true?

Did anyone in the West ever make a similar remark? If so, in what context?

Comment: Watching that video and it seems to be just a rant against the west with claims that the west is to subvert a civilization and decivilalize it and that they will be killed off when they are no longer needed. It appears that he is just ranting about his grievances and making claims that a single revolution wasn't a grass roots one with no evidence to back it up.

Comment: Note that Marxists [do no accept](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/revolution/), for instance, that the American Revolution was a revolution. So, a lot depends on definitions in such matters.

Comment: Furthermore, even other, broader definitions assume the endpoint of a revolution is replacing one government with another [by extra-constitutional means], so it's hard to argue that the latter [government] is not professionally organized, making the Q rather tautological. It's only with respect to what *initiates* a revolution (or just a rebellion) that the question makes some sense, in this framing.

Comment: Finally, it's [also] almost tautological that a revolution has a mass component, because that's what distinguishes it from a coup. As wikipedia puts it "while a coup is usually made by a small group and planned beforehand, a revolution or rebellion is usually started more spontaneously and by larger groups of uncoordinated people." (Also note the word "started" there, which relates to my previous  comment.)

Comment: Also, the related quote in the accepted answer implicitly defines revolution to be roughly any social change that didn't exist before. Which is also a valid dictionary definition, but perhaps not what the spy guy had in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most well known quotation on the subject is as follows:

> Never doubt that a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens can
> change the world; indeed, it's the only thing that ever has.

attributed to Margaret Mead. This quote [is first found in a published work](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/11/12/change-world/) in Chapter 6 of the 1982 book “Earth at Omega: Passage to Planetization” by Donald Keys who attributes it to her four years after her death, even though it does not appear in Ms. Mead's published works.

The quote [echoes a similar statement](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/11/12/change-world/) made in 1967 and recorded in the “New York Times”:

> The Rev R. H. Edwin Espy, the general secretary of the National
> Council of Churches, said that the project has been undertaken “in the
> conviction that informed, concerned and thoughtful citizens can change
> the world.”

KGB spy Yuri Bezmenov, however, more likely was alluding to the Leninist concept that communist revolutions are lead by [the Vanguard of the Proletariat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguardism) (usually in the form of the Communists Party) which has its roots in a larger Marxist political-economy theory understanding of historical processes.

Between Mead and Bezmenov, Mead is probably closer to the truth. While revolutions do require some sort of small group of committed and thoughtful citizens to achieve, they need not be "professional organizers" per se.

Western political scientists and historians have also observed that revolutions are frequently led not by people at the very bottom of a social class hierarchy who has most disadvantaged by the status quo, but instead by those who are close to its upper echelons who have been exclude from the ruling group, such as children of aristocrats who are excluded from receiving noble titles and lands in a primogeniture system.

Another example cited by some Western observers is that trade union leaders are often people with the innate abilities necessary to become members of a managerial-professional class who are excluded from it because the occupational eligibility and education necessary to hold those positions is not made available to them on a meritocratic basis.

Some of these Western academic concepts are touched upon, for example, in the book by Jack A. Goldstone, "[Revolutions: A Very Short Introduction](https://academic.oup.com/book/28409)" (December 2013).

An important intermediate concept involves thresholds for tipping points for changing norms in a society. According to Damon Centola et al. "Experimental Evidence for Tipping Points in Social Convention." *Science* (2018) DOI: 10.1126/science.aas8827 when 25 percent of people in a group adopt a new social norm, it creates a tipping point where the entire group follows suit. This shows the direct causal effect of the size of a committed minority on its capacity to create social change.

Other studies, however, use different models which much lower thresholds for major changes, such as a [logistic curve model](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:16b148ce-31d1-44b2-9857-510fbe375fbc/files/rjm214p18k) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)), and studies showing, e.g., that certain low single digit rates of electric car adoption typically lead to rapid widespread adoption of the technology later on. *See, e.g.* Stefanie Jannedy, Rens Bod, and Jennifer Hay *Probabilistic Linguistics* (2003) (Cambridge, Massachusetts: MIT Press. ISBN 0-262-52338-8) and Arnulf Grübler, "The Rise and Fall of Infrastructures: Dynamics of Evolution and Technological Change in Transport" (1990).

One of the leading works in this literature is Everett Rogers who is known mostly for his book, *[Diffusion of Innovations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_innovations)* (1962). This distinguishes several key groups at different stages of the process, first the innovators, then "early adopters", then the "early majority", the "late majority", and the "laggards." Early adopters filter potentially revolutionary innovations from all sources and make and break the innovations that actually succeed and become widely adopted in politics or otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure why the concerned citizens will work full time on overthrowing the regime and how they are going to defeat the state secret service whose main function tends to be not letting the concerned citizens meddling with the regime. What power level of citizens are we talking about? If it's province governor and minister level, perhaps.

Comment: Mead's saying always gives me the vibes of a pious homily.  A core of truth, sure.  An universal law, as implied by "it's the only thing"?  Makes people feel good, so it must be true seems to be the thinking.  And in the case of a full-on repressive regime like Stalin's or Kim's?  A likely deadly miscalculation.

Comment: @alamar Keep in mind that revolutions are not particularly common events. Life in North Korea is awful and its gone for about 70 years without one. The notion that people can change the world some of the time, says nothing about their win-loss record. Nor does it show that the revolutionaries are an improvement.

Comment: A good theory would feature a working win-loss prediction mechanism.

Comment: @alamar There are some people who have prediction models which are more complicated but none have wide acceptances and it is more art than science because translating the raw data into numbers to put into the model involves lots of subjective judgment calls (or at least intersubjective judgment calls).

Comment: @ohwilleke North Korea hasn't had a revolution because it's in a permanent state of purges.  Anyone who opposes the regime gets found out long before they can get any following and gets destroyed.  If the regime values loyalty above all, it doesn't matter that someone may bring value to the regime.  In order for a rebel to rise, they need to be tolerated while they rise.  And that only happens if there is something that the regime needs at least as much as loyalty.  Scientists were notoriously omnipresent among Soviet dissidents because what they offered could not be spared.

Comment: @wrod I don't disagree. The point is that just because you have a committed small group of people doesn't mean that you will have a successful revolution and in some circumstances a committed small group of people is nearly impossible to form. In N. Korea, if there was a revolution, you'd expect it to be lead by second or third tier communist party officials and family members of top tier communist party officials who have no power themselves. The models are better at predicting who will lead any revolution than whether it succeeds.

Comment: It's statistics vs visionaries.  Sometimes the ground becomes fertile and there are many groups and some of them succeed.  But sometimes it's someone seeing what no one has yet realized.  The system can fight many groups if the system doesn't depend on any of them, but if it does depend on some of them, an evolutionary change happens.  But a novelty can make the whole system irrelevant without it ever realizing that it's happening (not until it's too late).  E.g. the printing press.  It was supposed to support the system (to print more Bibles), but ended up reducing the Church's power.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I doubt Bezmenov was referring to Vanguardism with his comments. He mostly just seems to be criticizing the USA, without reference to any particular political philosophy.

Comment: @CharlieEvans Could be. I presumed because he no doubt had a Soviet education earlier in life.

Comment: @wrod All systems are in a permanent state of purges, including our current western capitalist one. That's *why* only the upper echelons can create successful revolutions!

Comment: @ohwilleke, I'd argue it's not Soviet/Marxist education, it's KGB (and generally secret service) education/job mindset. Putin also displays it prominently. If you are trained to do subversions, political influencing and other covert operations, if you know how effective they can be (and perhaps know a few successful examples unbeknown to general public) - in a word, if you are/were a member of a powerful "highly organized group", you tend to think that the whole world operates that way, and it's the norm...

Comment: @Zeus This makes a lot of sense and is very plausible.

Answer (score 6):

It's not true unless you have very specific definitions of grassroots and definition of highly organized group of conscientious and professional organizers.

Take for example the [Fall of communism in 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1989), in particular the [Peaceful revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaceful_Revolution) in Eastern Germany. Hundreds of thousands of East German citizens went to [demonstrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday_demonstrations_in_East_Germany) for reforms and freedom to leave the country after thousands of them had "escaped" via the Western German embassy in Prague. The leaders of the protest came from the middle of the society and notably from church, from circles of "intellectuals", but also from suppressed opposition politicians.

Was this a grassroots civil unrest movement or pure subversion by professionals? I'm not even sure what exactly is the point of Yuri Bezmenov there. He seems to somehow want to dismiss all civil revolutions of their legitimancy and put them on the same line as coup d'etats?

Anyway you can be the judge of how much the mentioned civil revolution was a grassroots movement and how much it wasn't.

Comment: That's not revolution. Gorbachev basically handed DDR to West Germany.

Comment: @alamar Well it's one of the few successful and peaceful revolutions. Gorbachev didn't lead the protests, so he's not relevant for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure you can call it a revolution. There's no hostile overthrowing of regime, it just decided to cease existing. Much like the USSR.

Comment: @alamar What would you call radical system change brought about by peaceful means?

Comment: A perestroika? :)

Comment: The fall started in Poland.  The Warsaw Pact was the full union (because all of it was under Moscow's control). And in Poland it did happen because of a long work done by the leaders of the "Solidarity" labor union.

Answer (score 6):

For revolution to work you need:

- lot's of people being unhappy with status quo
- some well organised group that would turn this dissatisfaction in to an actual movement able to formulate and achieve political goals

So is this glass half full or half empty?

Yuri Bezmenov seems to actually share views of Russian / Soviet establishment: revolutions don't happen because people are fed up with incompetent / corrupted establishment, they do happen because of some foreign sinister plots. This claim makes lot's of sense within context - you no longer have to be worried about your incompetence / corruption plus as long as you at least slightly helped in any revolution abroad you can take 100% credit for that.

In the West we want believe that powers come from the people, so it's supposed to come bottom up. In practice, there is a simple rationale for that - in any non-totalitarian state there are always legions of tiny radical political movements that are wannabe revolutionaries. Just as long as there is no latent mass support for them, they remain, tiny and irrelevant.

However, there is one big exception. In the West we're willing to claim that some social movements / revolutions are totally astroturfed when we oppose them so much that we either smear them or can't comprehend how otherwise anyone would support that:

For right wing: It's impossible that some ethnic or sexual minorities have genuine grievances about mistreatment thus whole "woke" movement must be result of subversion of Yuri Bezmenov former coworkers / plot of rich and powerful like World Economic Forum / big corporations trying to channel interest away from Occupy Wall Street movement towards something harmless for their bottom line

For left wing: It's impossible that working class and hollowing out medium class is unhappy about influx of migrants keeping their bargain power down, competing with them for safety net and public services or having disproportionally higher crime rate thus whole shift towards right-wing populism must be caused by Russian meddling / some greedy right-wing media pundits / charismatic leader mesmerizing masses.

Comment: Bezmenov certainly would share the Soviet views.  He was a KGB defector.  And in his videos he talked about KGB's methods for destabilizing and controlling other countries.  I think he made in the 70s.  Maybe in the early 80s, too.

Comment: The Soviets officially shared the Marxist view that economics and other comparable forces drive the evolution of the society. Do not know, maybe there was a disagreement between the official and actual view.

Comment: @Stančikas Officially? Yes. Unofficially? Their behaviour was totally inconsistent with that believe. There is not much point in putting so much effort in exporting revolution, if according to Marx they are about collapse under their own weight soon. Additionally, I first dismissed that as their propaganda, but it seems that Russian establishment genuinely believe that revolutions against them were happening because of foreign meddling and not because masses were fed up with their mismanagement.

Comment: It's quite possible that societies have sufficient quantities of unhappy people most of the time, which would make revolutions bound by the presense of organized revolutionaries and thus validate the question.

Comment: This answer is just unreferenced speculation. Much of it is overly simplistic, some of it is simply wrong.

Comment: @CharlieEvans Can you specify what exactly is wrong in this answer and which oversimplifications should be elaborated on?

Comment: Another one is Just Stop Oil being smeared as "some oil heiress"

Answer (score 5):

No.

[Tunisian revolution 2011.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisian_Revolution#Mohamed_Bouazizi_and_Sidi_Bouzid)

[People power Philippines 1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_Power_Revolution#Civil_disobedience_and_boycott_campaign_launch)

[Duvalier overthrow in 1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Duvalier_protest_movement)

These were all cases where the population was fed up with the government and spontaneously escalated protests till the government stood down.

Sure there may have been some influential people who helped it along but it wasn't some secret foreign cabal much beloved to repressive regimes everywhere when blaming discontent (cough, [Iran](https://www.iranintl.com/en/202210281987), cough).  Nor was it necessarily *a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens* that had somehow escaped the notice of the secret police up to that point.

Totalitarian governments are frequently at the knife edge of under or over-repressing.  USSR was stable enough when it had millions in Gulags, less stable when it tried to reform.  When you read history, you often see abrupt inflection points where a government lost control for no clear reason.  That can happen when a government is too brutal, it can happen when it is too lenient.  But a cause can very well be *mass discontent*, doesn't have to be *professional revolutionaries*.

Is Putin better off being brutal with anti-war protests?  Probably, as opposed to being conciliatory.  But over time always-on repression builds up pressure.  And if it blows up, can that really be blamed on the CIA running ops at scale in Russia?  Sure it can, *according to Yuri*.

Not to say many revolutions aren't manipulated.  But to say they all are is pure cover up for failing to satisfy your population's needs.

Look at the CCP's suppression of democratic aspirations in China - a large of it is about coopting the people.

Comment: I suspect that this oversimplifies greatly. In each of these cases I think you would find a small group of thoughtful concerned citizens laying the ground work and taking the lead when it happened. Not a foreign cabal probably, more likely local business people, lawyers, students, teachers and the like. No effective protest is truly spontaneous. Someone needs to spread the news, send memes on social media, set protest times and places and led marchers and convince them it will work. It is in the shadows but it is there.

Comment: If you say so.  I don't claim no nucleus of people assisted.  Only that they seemed to have been very secondary in these particular cases to a set of pent up grievances built up over time.  Minus the - somehow unrecognized, but supposedly vital - small groups those revolutions may very well have succeeded anyway.  Minus the masses' discontent the small groups would have gotten nowhere.  The Q is not about *nuances*, it is about *absolutes*, so some amount of oversimplification seems tolerable, to me.

Comment: Building up those grievances in a way that people recognize them as such alone is a huge and lengthy task. Clearly articulated discontent doesn't come from nowhere. It doesn't take a lot of people to articulate and crystalize it, but without people to articulate and circulate grievances until they become common sense the spark never lights and people shrug their shoulders, but their heads down, and keep taking it because it seems hopeless. They fail to treat a polarizing incident as a call to action.

Comment: @ohwilleke Have you ever been to a protest - anywhere, anytime? There are almost always some people de-facto leading the protest and they tend to be drawn from the smallish group of people, who have the experience and motivation (and sometimes resources) to lead protests. At the minimum, someone usually has to say "hey people, come to this specific place at this specific time" and they are the de facto organizer.

Comment: @user253751 I totally agree. I went to college at a hotbed of protest and I am intimately familiar with how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Actually no any

A revolution normally happens when the current situation over small incremental changes arrives to the a crisis deep enough to assume there is just not possible otherwise. These changes are generally assumed to be mostly technology-driven in the classic interpretation. I do not know if it could be something else. To make the long story short, "the bottoms" do not longer want to live as they used to. "The tops" may or may not want but anyway they just cannot anymore.

Certain organizing powers (movements, parties, political leaders) normally emerge at this point, but it is not they that are doing revolution. They are not leading people, people are pushing these leaders in front of them. Killing them is pointless, others will emerge. Sending organizers into the country from abroad makes no sense, they will not find the necessary support for they ideas. If they do, it is the problem with the society anyway.

The only way to organize the revolution from the side is to do the large scale military invasion or some large scale economic influence. Even this does not always work.

This is that I have been explained in the university. It may be somewhat quite along Marxism but this view is actually much older and comes [from the times of Renaissance](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/revolution) when people began to believe change was necessary for society to progress. These teachings do not account for the modern propaganda machinery (they were created when printed newspapers were the most evolved part of it).

Throughout the Middle Ages, Europeans also did what they could to prevent revolution and preserve the established order. The benefit of the democratic society is that changes can happen peacefully, by simply electing the new leaders that agree to implement new policies. With no democracy, it is like a steam boiler without safety valve -  this will not prevent the steam from escaping, just it will happen later but then in much more destructive way.

In other words, any saying that revolution happens because of some organized "foreign agents" or "local agents" is just not scientific. That "professional organizers" can do is to make the mature transition timely and less painful.

Comment: You are reiterating what people are led to believe about revolutions. But why we should assume it is true? Is it confirmed by observations?

Comment: I never thought that National Geographic was a authoritative source on political science. They just reiterate the marxism-induced narratives about revolution. I wonder if it's validated by hard science.

Comment: And what are your "authoritative sources on political science"? Who loses track on the history and existing scientific knowledge, can manipulated any way preferred.

Comment: We are currently in the search of those. I'm not aiming for trials with a control group, obviously, but some kind of paper with serious analysis will be nice.